# Singleton class Arraylist is empty

Tags: java, android, arraylist, singleton

I have created a singleton ArrayList class in android which is following.

```
public class SingletonArrayList  {

    private static SingletonArrayList mInstance;
    private ArrayList<String> userNameList = null;

    public static SingletonArrayList getInstance() {
        if(mInstance == null)
            mInstance = new SingletonArrayList();
        return mInstance;
    }

    private SingletonArrayList() {
        userNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    // retrieve array from anywhere
    public ArrayList<String> getArray() {
        return this.userNameList;
    }

    //Add element to array
    public void addToArray(String value) {
        userNameList.add(value);
    }
}
```

I'm calling this singleton ArrayList in my activity2. It's working fine there(it contains data!).

**activty2:**

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, SingletonArrayList.getInstance().getArray());
```

But in activtiy1 it's returing an empty list.

**activity1:**

```
Log.i("single",SingletonArrayList.getInstance().getArray().toString());

if(SingletonArrayList.getInstance().getArray().contains(username1)) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Username already Exists. Please select a different username", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return;
}
```

Basically, the problem is that ArrayList is coming empty in one activity and contains data in another activity. Any solutions?

Comment: Where are the calls to `addToArray()`?

Comment: I'm calling this in activity2 in the onChildAdded method of firebase                           SingletonArrayList.getInstance().getArray().add(userClassObj.getFullName());

Comment: Then why would you expect it to be populated in activity1?

Comment: i can use simpe add instead addToArray right?

Comment: I think you need to read about passing data between activities: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application

Comment: This does not look like a good candidate for a singleton.

Comment: what i want to achieve is to access and update the  arraylist values in multiple activties. so what do you suggest i should be doing here to acheive this? And I can't use Intent

Comment: Then you probably need to persist your data